Append Documentation (KDoc) into an android library file (.aar)
After searching for a while I could not find a proper / updated way of
how to add the code documentation into my library.
I am not using a remote repository at all, I wish to add the .aar file manually to the app module.
Some tries which haven't worked:
tasks.register('sdkDocs', Jar) {
    group("documentation")
    description("Generate documentation")
    archiveFileName = "$sdkBaseArchiveName-sources.jar"
    def sdkDir = "$projectDir/src/main/java/com/agenatoolssdk/sdk"
    def publicAPI = [
            "$sdkDir/AgenaApi.kt",
            "$sdkDir/ApiBattery.kt",
            "$sdkDir/ApiButton.kt",
            "$sdkDir/ApiLed.kt",
            "$sdkDir/ApiSatCom.kt"
    ]
    // from(sourceSets.main.get().allJava)
    from publicAPI
}

tasks.register('addDocsToAar', Jar) {
    mustRunAfter(assemble)
    group("documentation")
    description("Add the generated documentation to the .aar file")
    setArchiveFileName("myModuleWithSources.aar")
    setDestinationDirectory(file("build"))
    from zipTree("build/outputs/aar/$sdkBaseArchiveName-release.aar")
    from fileTree("build").include("libs/$sdkBaseArchiveName-sources.jar")
}

